# Javascript regular expression to check a string like x.0.0

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
    if (/0\.0$/.test(text))
```

I am using this successfully to check for text ending in 0.0 such as:

```
1.0.0 
2.0.0
3.0.0
```

However it also works for the following:

```
1.10.0
2.10.0
```

Is there a way I can change this expression so it only gives true for the first 3 values and not the second two?

Here's my complete code:

```
    if (/0\.0$/.test(text))
        pad = 10;
    else if (/\.0$/.test(text))
        pad = 35;
    else
        pad = 60;
    tdToPad.css('margin-left', pad);
```

For the case where text is 2.10.0 it should pad with 35 but it is padding with 10.

Comment: also you can use `/(?:\.0){2,}$/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a problem with using `/\.0\.0$/` ?

Comment: Well it seems that this test is passing for 1.10.0 and it should fail.

Comment: The addition of the literal period at the front of the regex I suggested will only match strings of the form: foo.0.0

Comment: Also f you want to be sure the thing before the first period is a number, use something like `/\d+\.0\.0$/`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(/\.0\.0$/.test(text))
```

and if you want a number at the beginning

```
if(/^\d+\.0\.0$/.test(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
 if (/\d+\.0\.0$/.test(text)) // if number.0.0
        pad = 10;
    else if (/\d+\.[1-9]+\d+?\.0$/.test(text)) // if 0 at the end
        pad = 35;
    else
        pad = 60;
    tdToPad.css('margin-left', pad);
```